# Can someone explain why i'm getting 9 & 5 instead of 36880 & 375

Tags: javascript

For my return, I'm getting 9 and 5 instead of 362880 and 375. Can someone explain what I missed?

```js
function multiplyAll(num){  // declare a function name multyplyAll with a num parameter
   for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++){  // for loop to iterate base on the length of the parameter. 
     num *= num[i]  // multiplies them all together. 
   }
   return num   // function outpout 
 }
 console.log(multiplyAll(9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 3)) // should log: 362880
 console.log(multiplyAll(5, 5, 5, 3)) // should log: 375
```

Comment: You’re passing several arguments but accept only one: a number. Then you act as if that single number was an array. You mean `function multiplyAll(...num){`…`}`. Then some initial number is also missing: `let result = 1;`, `result *= num[i]`, `return result;`. Read the docs: [Rest parameters](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `num` without `rest parameters` then only the first value will get assign to `num`. You are treating like `num` is an array but `num` is just of type number

There is no `length` property on `num`, Because `num` is of type number. It won't run the `for` loop and return the first element i.e `9` and `5`

You should use collect then in to an array using [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
function multiplyAll(...num) {
  // declare a function name multyplyAll with a num parameter
  let res = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    // for loop to iterate base on the length of the parameter.
    res *= num[i]; // multiplies them all together.
  }
  return res; // function outpout
}
console.log(multiplyAll(9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 3)); // should log: 362880
console.log(multiplyAll(5, 5, 5, 3)); // should log: 375
```

You can also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here as:

```js
function multiplyAll(...num) {
  return num.reduce((acc, curr) => acc * curr, 1);
}
console.log(multiplyAll(9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 3)); // should log: 362880
console.log(multiplyAll(5, 5, 5, 3)); // should log: 375
```

Comment: Thanks for the update guys! the rest parameters make sense.